# Hibernate-get table names and its column details runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to get database listname and tables's details at runtime.

I'm try to make an tool to load db dynamically via Hibernate.
Its process:

Input infoDB(name,user,pass,etc)->load table name-> load table detail.

When I looked into it, they're all using XML  with all tables in it.

Any idea will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean under `load db dynamically via Hibernate`?

Comment: that's the flow (User Case) of my tool.